# How to label rows based on if statement in python?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am trying to create a `Labels` column labelling my data, I've tried adapting answers from similar questions but gotten stuck with what I specifically need.

My data looks like this (unfortunately I can't provide a real example):

```
Gene   CLN
Gene1  cardiovascular
Gene2  Cardiovascular
Gene3  Neurological
```

Currently I am trying:

```
df['Labels'] = ['Probable' if df['CLN'].str.contains("cardio", case=False) else NA for x in df['CLN']]
```

The condition is to find all rows in the `CLN` column and label them if they have a partial string match for 'cardio', and ignore labeling/doing anything with any rows that don't match, but my code gives an error (`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`) - I am not confident with python so I'm not sure to do to address this?

Expected output:

```
Gene   CLN             Labels
Gene1  cardiovascular  Probable
Gene2  Cardiovascular  Probable
Gene3  Neurological    NA
```

The idea long term is I could write another line when I want to add more labels than just `Probable` too, so doing something like:

```
df['Labels'] = ['Probable' if df['CLN'].str.contains("cardio", case=False) else NA for x in df['CLN']]
df['Labels'] = ['Unlikely' if df['CLN'].str.contains("neurological", case=False) else NA for x in df['CLN']]
```

But I'm worried these would cancel each other out, overwriting NA over labels.

Comment: `NA` needs to be in quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.select`:

```
df['Labels'] = np.select((df['CLN'].str.contains("cardio", case=False),
                          df['CLN'].str.contains("neurological", case=False)),
                         ('Probable', 'Unlikely'),
                         np.nan              # or 'NA' if it fits you better
                        )
```

Comment: Thank you for this, is there a way to get it to work when you only have 1 condition? (the cardio one) it gives me an error ```ValueError: list of cases must be same length as list of conditions``` when I just try with one

Comment: With One condition use np.where